# css3 : how to make div go up to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="div1">some div whose height may change</div>
<div id="div2">
  this div should go up to bottom
  <div>
    <input id="chat" type="text" placeholder="stick to bottom of yellow div">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Css:

```
html,body {
  heihgt:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#div1{
  height:60px;
  background-color:red;
}
#div2{
  position:relative;
 background-color:yellow; 
 height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jv82z52g/

How to make div2 take the whole space up to bottom of the page ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only do it with Javascript.

Comment: "pretty" is the keyword

Comment: So you need <div2> to be a footer?

Comment: div2 shoudl start when div1 stops and go up to bottom (fill the whole space left)

Comment: I edited your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jv82z52g/13/). tell me if it works

Comment: This is not good enough; the yellow overflows : and I need to place an input at the BOTTOM of the yellow

Comment: Hmm i found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzf4x/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct the `height` typo in your CSS, and make `body` a **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)**:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  //children should go down the page
}
```

Then add this style:

```
#div2 {
  flex: 1;  //take up remainder of space
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ooak2xqc/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css flexbox specification.
Give your body element these styles:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

On your #div1 add this rule:

```
flex: 0 1 auto;
```

While on your #div2 add:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

Also dont forget to correct your `height` typo on the html, body selector.

I suggest you read some articles about the flexbox specification: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jv82z52g/6/

Answer (score -2):

Try this in your div2 css:

```
position: absolute;
background-color: yellow;    
bottom: 0;
```

Remove the height in your div2-class.

Comment: add in the following css tag instead;

```body {position: absolute; height:100%; width:100% } ```
That'll do the trick.

Comment: Not good: it now starts at the TOP of the page ! and do not forget I write: red height is variable !

Comment: Remove height property.

Comment: Ahh yes, it was mentioned in the ```html, div``` class but it's misspelt. That explains it.